# Access first datum in Firebase snapshot

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am attempting to access the attributes of the first datum only in a Firebase snapshot which consists of 10 URLs. No matter what I try, however, I am getting the whole snapshot. My code looks like:

```
myDataRef.limitToLast(10).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
 var newImg = snapshot.child("url");
  console.log(newImg);
});
```

Is there a way to specify [0] or the like on the whole snapshot so that I'll just get the first datum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's tricky to be sure without seeing your data structure, but I think you're looking for:

```
myDataRef.limitToLast(10).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
  var newImg;
  snapshot.forEach(function(urlSnapshot) {
    if (!newImg) {
      newImg = urlSnapshot.val();
    }
  });
  console.log(newImg);
});
```

The `forEach()` loops over all child keys of the `snapshot` and invokes the inner callback with a `DataSnapshot` of each of them.

The `newImg = urlSnapshot.val();` will just get the value of that child. You may have to modify this bit based on your data structure.

Answer (score 1):

Let me preference this by saying there is no guaranteed order for how data is stored in firebase - the concept of first item or index 0th item is determined by how the data is stored and how the data is retrieved.

So the best bet is to either load all the values as a snapshot and sort by a specified value (like date or height etc) and pick off the 0th index from the sorted array, or load in a subset of data and use queryOrderedByChild or queryStartingAtValue

This may be an answer to the question: it does retrieve only the first value within a specified node:

```
users
  user_0
    firstName: "Fred"
  user_1
    firstName: "Bill"
  user_2
    firstName: "Ted"
```

and the code

```
usersRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
   if snapshot.value is NSNull {
      print("snapshot was NULL")
   } else {
     print(snapshot)
   }
})
```

and the result

```
Snap (user_0) {
    firstName = Fred;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to store the snapshot as an array first and access it as [0].

I'm not at my mac computer (I'm answering your question as for iOS, but I believe the concept is the same) so this is just from my memory, but it works if the syntax is correct:

var newImgArray = snapshot.children.objects as? [FSSnapshot]
var newImg = newImgArray[0].value

Comment: Afraid I'm getting "undefined." I tried `var newImgArry = snapshot.val();` 

  `console.log(newImgArry[0].value);`

Comment: I think .childAdded actually is called 10 times if you query for 10 items as opposed to returning all 10 items in one array.

If that's the case, just create an array outside of your Firebase call and append each snapshot into your array. Seems like you're not working in iOS so I can't help with the syntax, but the idea is to create an array outside, and just use myArray.append(snapshot). Then after your Firebase call, you can access myArray[0]